# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.activiti.bpmn.model.TaskWithFieldExtensions

Tags: activiti

I am getting an error.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>
> org.activiti.bpmn.model.TaskWithFieldExtensions

I have already `added org.activiti.bpmn.model` dependency. Any pointers ?

Comment: That class is pretty new, see https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-bpmn-model/src/main/java/org/activiti/bpmn/model/TaskWithFieldExtensions.java, it is in no release yet. 

What are you trying to do? Build from source? Use your own snapshot or something else?